# The span does not belong to a source snapshot of the projection snapshot - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm getting following exception on Visual Studio 2019 while trying to expand references details for some properties.

> The span does not belong to a source snapshot of the projection
>   snapshot

[image: Throwing exception on Title property]

PictureModel(screenshot) has four properties, only two of them throwing this exception.

[image: No exception]

As you see there is no exception for the last property.

Looks like the exception happening for some properties and Visual Studio 2017 works fine.

Any clue? any work-around?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the CodeLens provider.  Send feedback through VS and have the product team take a look.

Comment: Gettng the same error. Original solution using VS 2017 Community, opened in VS 2019 Community.  My observations - If I open or close various tabs that contain the reference, the 'references' count changes accordingly. Further, references in .cshtml files created after opening the solution in VS2019 map as expected if that file is open, but if an earlier .cshtml file is open, the error message comes up.

Comment: I recently had this issue with a partial Razor view in an ASP.Net Core 3.1 project. This partial view also was not committing correctly to Gitlab when checking out new branches. I would always get a version of the page that was a few versions old. I deleted the partial view, added a new one with the same name, and pasted the code back in. This resolved the issue in my case.